# How to open android app if app is installed or navigate to google play store by single link?

Tags: android, google-play, android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking

I need to implement this logic:

1. user clicked on a link on an Android phone
2. if my application is installed - the application opens
3. if the application is not installed - open the Google Play page with my application

I need to use just 1 link. As I understand link should be looks like `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`

I use compose navigation

So my question is how exactly should I implement this, what exactly should the link look like and should I add an `assetlinks.json` file to our website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need an [App-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) feature

edit:

1.Register some domain, e.g. `bazinga.com`

2.Use [App-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) for making your app a default specific-domain-url handler/opener

```
  <data android:scheme="http" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
  <data android:host="bazinga.com" />
```

note you can declare even one strict address, not whole domain, with `android:android:pathPrefix` (or similar)

3.Prepare your domain behavior - e.g. `https://bazinga.com/open_app` url redirect to App Store or Google Play (this may be distinguished by User-Agent)

4.On Android devices with app installed it will be opened and you may read an url which is delivered to `Activity` in `Intent`, or not if you don't need to (just enjoy autostart)

PS. Note that you need `autoVerify` param and some additional file on server/domain side (confirming you aren't hijacking traffic of not-your domain) - this will make your app auto-open on url press. Without `autoVerify` (or verification failed?) you will create a deep linking solution - Android will ask user in which app url should be opened, your app or web browser, and there are "only once" and "always" options. In general 80% of this picks are web browser and "always", no matter of an app type... ehh, users..

Comment: I understand, but I don’t understand what the link and code in the manifest should look like, when I add a host like "play.google.com" it doesn’t work, maybe I need to intercept the intent?

Comment: none of these, try to look also at [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links?hl=pl). sadly don't have much time for more complex description at now... but in short: play store link isn't the one you should put into manifest

Comment: but Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated (

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it like this:

In the Manifest file:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

      <data android:scheme="http" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
      <data android:host="bazinga.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

and the link is `intent://bazinga.com/&app_store_redirect=android#/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.bazinga;end`

My app package name: `com.bazinga`

Comment: very surprised this is working... is it? have you checked on few devices with different OS versions? search engines doesn't show any useful results for ""app_store_redirect=android""... any doc for that? note that link isn't "uniwersal" like Firebase solution, will work ONLY on Android and not on iOS (as this platform isn't using `Intent`s)

Comment: seems like it works not with all of android os versions. i've read about firebase solution but it will be shut down in 2025 so I can't use it. do u have any other ideas?(

Comment: check out edit of my answer